# Why is my dog defensive at home but scared outside?

Tags: dogs, behavior

I have noticed that my dog is more defensive and violent when at home. Once a dog came to our house, my dog attacked it and injured it and the other dog ran away.

Another day, my dog saw the same dog on the street, it just ran away, the other dog pursued it but as soon as my dog got to the front of our gate, it turned back and attacked the other dog until the other dog ran away.

Is this a normal dog behavior?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dogs can be very territorial animals.

When at home, your dog is in his territory and is just responding to what he believes is an outside intruder coming into his territory.  This is why your dog immediately responded in the second case as soon as entered his yard.

But in the 2nd case, why he ran is because he was outside of his territory and did not want to challenge the other dog outside of where he felt safe.

Now is this normal?  I wouldn't say it is abnormal, but if you dog will attack anyone (or at least any dog) that enters his yard, then that is something that needs dealt with because he could possible seriously injure someone (or some dog) who just happens to come into you yard.

Comment: It doesn't attack people, only dogs that enter our yard

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi dog doesn't treat human and dogs the same way. So your dog may have territory problem with dogs only.

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi Ankit's point is correct (and someone was meant as a generic multi-species sense anyway), however my point of mentioning it was that the dog might not have injured anyone **yet**.  Generally speaking (and it depends on the laws of the country) the first time a dog bites someone could be the last time as well.  If you think it is progressing in that direction, it needs to be dealt with.

Comment: @psubsee2003 It has never made advances to people before but it had always attacked dogs (esp male) that came near my house

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi You mentioned that your dog injured another one so you really want to address that and get him to be fine with other dogs in his home